# How to get cross referencing in a Python project?

Tags: python, ide

I'd really like full support for cross referencing in Python, in particular in Django. I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to emacs, but I love it dearly. I've used and been very impressed with the ada-mode in emacs and its cross referencing but that requires compilation artifacts. Is there a way to get emacs to do it with Python?

By "Cross Referencing" I mean that I can jump to the file containing a method definition from any reference in the project.

Comment: Have a look at [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

Comment: Did you try anaconda-mode? https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) can do this with `elpy-goto-definition` (bound to `M-.` by default).

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Look into anaconda-mode: https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode

For cross-referencing, you can mark the reference and then use `M-x anaconda-mode-usages` to easily see the cross-references.